# Send email to multiple address in powershell

Tags: powershell

$PE is holds the email address of a user which is retrieved from AD user profile. I need to sent email to that user. As it keeps on changing as per user profile I am finding it difficult to pass it into this email function.

```bsh
$PE=$(Get-aduser -filter {name -like $name} -properties mail).mail
Function abc($subject,$body,$PE)
{
    
    $Htmlbody="____"
    $toaddress = $PE
    
    If (attachment -eq "")
    {
        Send-emailmessage -from "abc@xym.com" -bodyashtml -To $toaddress -body $htmlbody -subject $subject
    }
}
```

I tried the above but I am getting an error for -To field and I don't see email address in $PE whereas $PE is holding the value before calling this function and inside the function it's empty.

Here is the error :Cannot validate argument on parameter 'To' .the argument is null or empty . Provide an argument that is not null or empty . Then try again

Comment: You have several issues. param $Body is never used, `attachment` is missing its `$`. Are you sure that $PE is actually filled by your script that retrieves AD user information?

Comment: Could you please share the error message as well as it already shows quite often the solution to the issue. How do you fill the variable `$PE`?

Comment: Here is the error :Cannot validate argument on parameter 'To' .the argument is null or empty . Provide an argument that is not null or empty . Then try again

Comment: Please add it completely to your question - not as another comment. Thanks in advance. (you should format the error message as code as well please)

Comment: @ Peter , I have not typed the $body here as it's working fine for me , and I have tested the code in dedug mode, $PE holding the user email address .

Comment: $PE is holding the value but you;re not passing it to the function. Don't use the same variable name for function parameters that you are using in your main script.

Comment: Remove the `$`  before (Get-aduser)  `$pe = (get-aduser)`. 
`abc -subject "test" -body "a nice body" -pe $pe` works fine for me except for the body ofcourse which is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) Variables defined in a function are applicable only inside that function unless you scope otherwise - see Powershell documentaiton about "Scoping" for details

(2) Create the function then PASS the parameters to the function. It's easier to understand this if you use the "longhand" way of passing parameters

```
$PE=$(Get-aduser -filter {name -like $name} -properties mail).mail



Function abc {
    Param(
    $subject,
    $body,
    $toaddress)

    Send-emailmessage -from "abc@xym.com" -bodyashtml -To $toaddress -body $body -subject $subject
}

abc -subject "MySubject" -body "____" -toaddress $PE
```